# Corrupted display in mint linux thinkpad X240

Tags: linux-mint, thinkpad, corruption, xcursor

[image: How windows appear]Good day to all of you, I had this problem with manjaro, I erased my disk afterwords and installed mint, I encountered it again after a shutdown. It's a startup with X cursor shape and no basic window operations(closing, resizing, hiding..).
I am using thinkpad X240.
Please any help, I really need it.